# Android studio progressDialog in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My first post here, so excuse me if it's in the wrong place or if I've got one or two things wrong. Also I'm a serious beginner, so assume I know very little.
Thanks...
I am creating a simple app in android studio where I am trying to register a user on an online server.
I got it to work (it registers the user on the server), but now I am trying to add a progress dialog so that when the app is connecting to the server this will display. 
My code below seems to work - the dialog appears then disappears straight away but at the end I get a message saying "Unfortunately LoginRegister has stopped"

Any ideas what is wrong with my code...here it is

```
package com.example.android.loginregister;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Jon on 2015/09/15.
 */

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    //declares a context variable
    Context ctx;

    //declares an alert dialog object
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //declare constructor will need to be passed a context
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    }

    //in this me`enter code here`thod (which happens before execution of the object) the alert dialog object is instantiated
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //set up url connections
        String reg_url = "http://jontestdb.webege.com/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://jontestdb.webege.com/login.php";
        String method = params[0];

        if (method.equals("register")){
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];

            try {

                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") +"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") +"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();

                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();

                return "Registration success...";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } ;
        }
        else if(method.equals("login")){

            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //defines communication method
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                //need to send info to the server
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //gets response from server
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                //now need to get output stream from connection so first create output stream object
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                //need to specify data - used the post method so have to encode data
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("login_pass", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();

                outputStream.close();

                //get response from server
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                //need buffered reader now
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

                //now need to get information from bufferedreader
                String response = "";
                String line = "";

                //this is saying that if buffered reader.read line is not null then get the info from buffered reader
                //the data obtained from the read line method and stored in the line variable is the added the response variable
                //seems as though bufferedreader contains the query result
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    response += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                //this returns the response which should be the name of the user
                return response;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



        if (result.equals("Registration success...")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        if (progressDialog != null){
            progressDialog.dismiss();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat

Comment: Hi. I cant seem to repeat the error now, I think I may have fixed it without meaning to haha. If I do manage to I will post the logcat here. But for now lets assume this is post is solved. Thank you for your reply Arsal Imam and apologies for any inconvenience. I'm sure I will stumble across many more issues along my way though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use Volley and my imlementation is the next:

```
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://ejemplo.com/funciones_php/ServicioRest.php?Func=DispConocido&IdDispositivo="+text;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Principal.this, "Cargando", "Espere unos segundos", true);
                        final String r = response;
                        // Ejecuta el codigo despues de 1.5 segundos
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                               //Your source here
                            }
                        }, 1500);

                        /*Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, response, duration);
                        toast.show();*/
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);